# Insertar texto en un input al presionar una tecla

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quería ver si me podrían ayudar con esto.
Tengo un problema en PHP que cuando quiero publicar algo en mi blog no reconoce los saltos de linea como `<br>`, sino que lo publica todo junto.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que cuando presione la tecla *enter* me añada un `<br>` al `input`?

Comment: Por favor agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado como se sugiere en [ask].

Comment: ¿Y porqué en vez de un elemento tipo `<input>` mejor no usas un elemento tipo `<textarea>`?

Comment: Deberías usar un [`<textarea>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

Comment: con un <textarea> ya detecta los saltos de linea?

Comment: quedó así, pero tampoco...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En efecto deberías usar un textarea pero respondiendo a tu pregunta si se puede añadir un br a un input de la siguiente manera.

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].onkeypress = function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            input[i].value = input[i].value + '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Texto">
```

Comment: Y si uso un textarea? sería lo mismo pero cambiando el input por textarea no?

Comment: var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (let i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++) {
    textarea[i].onkeypress = function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            textarea[i].value = textarea[i].value + '<br>';
        }
    }
}

Comment: o no, perdona la ignorancia

Comment: Considera explicar tu aporte

Comment: el <textarea> por defecto te inserta un <br> cada que das clic en enter pero si lo necesitas insertar textualmente pues si en efecto daría el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Un elemento de tipo `input` no "guarda" los saltos de línea, esta concebido para entradas sencillas: texto no demasiado largo y en una línea. Para introducir un texto largo, con saltos de línea en un formulario, se emplearía un `textarea`.

#### Propuesta de solución: insertar saltos de línea HTML en textarea al pulsar Enter

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="test"></textarea>
    
    <script>
        const element = document.getElementById('test');
        element.addEventListener(
            'keydown',
            (event) => {
                if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                    element.value = element.value + '<br>';
                }
            }
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Explicación:** asocio un evento de tecla al *textarea*, cuando detecta el evento y la tecla pulsada en *Enter* modifica el contenido del *textarea* añadiendo `<br>` al final del contenido.

#### Propuesta de solución: añadir el HTML en el servidor

Cuando el formulario se envía al servidor, tienes que recoger y tratar su contenido. Si no vas a introducir más HTML en el formulario, puedes "limpiar" el texto y seguidamente añadir los saltos de línea HTML, si bien esto puedes hacerlo antes de guardarlo o de *pintarlo*.

Si recibes el texto con los saltos de línea HTML incorporados una función interesante es `strip_tags()` que limpia tags HTML del texto pero permite conservar los seleccionados (lista blanca), ejemplo:

```
$str = 'Hola<br><hr>mundo';
$str = strip_tags($str, '<br>'); // Salida: 'Hola<br>mundo'
echo $str;
```

Para transformar saltos de línea del texto plano a HTML con PHP:

```
<?php
$str = trim($_POST['texto']);
$str = preg_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br>', $str);
// Salida posible: 'Hola<br>mundo'
```

o bien:

```
<?php
$str = trim($_POST['texto']);
$str = nl2br($str);
// Salida posible: 'Hola<br />mundo'
```

La función `nl2br()` tiene esta finalidad específica, por defecto añade tags XHTML, es decir `<br />` en lugar de HTML `<br>`. Añade `false` como segundo parámetro para obtener estos últimos.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php